# Make separate list of same object in the list

Tags: java

I have list of object and there is a chance that we have multiple duplicates of different object now my goals is to iterate through the list and store same object in separate list. Any ideas on how to achieve that.

Input list

> [1,3,3,1,4]

What i want to achieve

> [1,1]
>
> [3,3]
>
> [4]

Comment: order, iterate { create new array if old val is different and put old array to some array of arrays } ... at the end you will have [1,3,3,1,4] => [[1,1], [3,3], [4]]... where is the problem? looks like a basic programming excercise

Comment: Do you mean by same object, really the same object or a different object by the same class? Because if it's really the same object, you can just check if the list already contains that object and only add it to the list if the object isn't in it yet. Also I don't see the point of having multiple lists of references that point to a single point per list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do this with the new stream API. But I'm not very familiar with it yet. If I were you, I would do this:

```
int[] list = {1, 3, 3, 1, 4};
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> listsMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int i: list) {
    if (!listsMap.containsKey(i)) {
        listsMap.put(i, new ArrayList<>());
        listsMap.get(i).add(i);
    } else {
        listsMap.get(i).add(i);
    }
}
System.out.println(listsMap);
```

Explanation:

First, we create a map that stores the lists (line 2). This is used to find the correct list to add the item into when we loop through the array.

Now we loop through the array (line 3). We check whether we have already encountered the item before (line 4). If we have not, add a new `ArrayList` to the map with the current item as the key (line 5). Then we put the item into the newly created array(line 6). If we have encountered the item before, just add the item to the array with the key of that item(line 8).